# unable to clone git repository on laptop, however, cloned successfully on dev machine

Tags: git, git-extensions

I have successfully installed git on a windows server 2008 machine and set up ssh.

I have successfully cloned a repository on my developer machine (windows 7), but when I tried to clone it on my laptop (windows 7), it is giving me the error:

```
unable to open connection. Host does not exist
```

I can connect to it with putty successfully, and also set the environment variable. I cannot identify what I am missing. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have also check by setting proxy off but nothing works.  Any help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually when I tried to clone it was also giving the error in alert box that

```
The server's host key is not cached in the registry
```

with option yes or no then I selected Yes then it gave me the error

```
unable to open connection. Host does not exist
```

So the solution is saving the host key in registry

Open up cmd and go to path of plink (mine was C:\Program Files (x86)\GitExtensions\PuTTY)
and type plink user@whateveryourserver.com

This will prompt you to save the host key in registry , and enter yes, then try your git command again, and it should be working.