# Behavior of bat and Powershell is different when clicked vs run from respective consoles, specifically with git

Tags: git, powershell, batch-file

This post appears wordy, but there's actually not much here to read. Just figured more details > less details.

I am working on some tools to speed up my git workflow. I found/modified a PowerShell script that attempts to update all git branches:

```
function PullAllBranches() {
$branches = git branch
foreach($branch in $branches){
    $fixedBranch = $branch.Substring(2, $branch.Length - 2) # extract actual name
    $trackedExpression = "branch." + $fixedBranch + ".merge"
    $trackedBranch = git config --get $trackedExpression # returns refs/heads/master (?)
 #  Write-Host($trackedBranch)
    if(![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($trackedBranch))
    {
        Write-Host('Pulling branch: ' + $fixedBranch)
        git checkout "$fixedBranch" | Out-Null # Pipe to stdout
        git pull 
    }
    else {
        Write-Host('Branch "' + $fixedBranch + '" has no tracked remote')
    }
}
}

PullAllBranches

Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

It fails saying the repo does not exist:

```
Pulling branch: master
git : Switched to branch 'master'
At C:\Users\username\Git\username\csv-plottr\pull_updates.ps1:15 char:9
+         git checkout "$fixedBranch" | Out-Null # Pipe to stdout
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Switched to branch 'master':String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

git : Unable to open connection:
At C:\Users\username\Git\username\csv-plottr\pull_updates.ps1:16 char:9
+         git pull
+         ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Unable to open connection::String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Host does not exist
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

However, stepping through the code, appears it should work. Digging into this, I tried a simple git pull origin master in PowerShell CLI:

```
PS C:\Users\username\Git\username\csv-plottr> git pull origin master
From gh-gitlab:username/csv-plottr
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
PS C:\Users\username\Git\username\csv-plottr>
```

Where 'gh-gitlab' is a SSH identity pointing to a gitlab server on my LAN(equivalent to 10.0.0.xxx:username/csv-plottr). This approach works fine, making me think running a PowerShell script executes in a different environment when run from PowerShell ISE or something than typing into the CLI. I printed working directory in both cases and it is the same. Are there any PowerShell/Windows with more experience than I have who could shed some light or point me in the right direction on google?

Curiously, I tried the same thing in a batch file, what I am trying to get away from using, with similar results. From cmd:

```
C:\Users\username\Git\username\csv-plottr>git pull origin master
From gh-gitlab:username/csv-plottr
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
```

And from the batch file merely containing:

```
git pull origin master
pause
```

Running by double clicking, I get:

```
C:\Users\username\Git\username\csv-plottr>git pull origin master
Unable to open connection:
Host does not existfatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

C:\Users\username\Git\username\csv-plottr>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

But CDing to the directory and running it by typing the name of the script gives:

```
C:\Users\username\Git\username\csv-plottr>.\pull_updates.bat

C:\Users\username\Git\username\csv-plottr>git pull origin master
From gh-gitlab:username/csv-plottr
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.

C:\Users\username\Git\username\csv-plottr>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

success! It says the repo is up to date in this case.

What gives??? Why is this behavior different and what could I do (or google about) to create the same behavior? I echo'd %CD% (pwd) and it checks out. I have fought this all day, and finally figured I'd ask for help with what I thought would be a 15 minute job. I'm stumped. Thanks in advance.

---

Edit for /u/mklement0:

I wanted double click functionality for powershell, so I set this registry key:
HKCR\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\Open\Command

to

"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -File "%1"%*

Which fixes both troubles with running powershell and execution policy, and convenience of just double clicking. As best I can tell, this should be identical to going into a powershell window, CDing to the correct dir, and calling your ps1 script.

But when double clicking my ps1 script I get the same issues:

```
Pulling branch: dev
Switched to branch 'dev'
Unable to open connection:
Host does not existfatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Pulling branch: master
Switched to branch 'master'
Unable to open connection:
Host does not existfatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Press Enter to exit:
```

vs calling from a PS console:

```
PS C:\Users\username\Git\username\csv-plottr> .\pull_updates.ps1
Pulling branch: dev
Switched to branch 'dev'
Already up to date.
Pulling branch: master
Switched to branch 'master'
Already up to date.
Press Enter to exit:
```

success!

This happens with batch files too. This was not done in the PowerShell ISE either, just to rule that out.

Comment: I avoid Windows so can't help much, but "host does not exist" looks suspicious. The fact that the host name is `gh-gitlab` (not `gh-gitlab.some.dom.ain` also looks suspicious. Perhaps host name resolution changes based on some CLI-provided key.

Comment: Yeah I try to avoid windows, but I want to maintain cross platform compatibility for this. gh-gitlab is an SSH identity set up to point to a gitlab server on my LAN (added). It has been extremely reliable in the past, and I don't think it is the issue. If auth fails I think it says something like failure (public key).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do not use the PowerShell ISE to *run* your scripts** (for development, it may be OK, but you should know the pitfalls):

- The ISE's PowerShell *host* is not a true console and behaves differently, which is likely the problem in this case (see below).
- **All code invocations run in the *same session*, via *dot-sourcing***, so that actions of previous invocations can affect subsequent invocations.

**Specifically, the ISE reports a (non-terminating) error whenever an external program such as `git` writes to *stderr***, even though that may not indicate an actual error (external utilities write any *non-data* messages, such as status information, to stderr); only an external program's *exit code* - reflected in `$LASTEXITCODE` in PowerShell - truly signals success vs. failure.

Note, however, that despite the error "noise", execution continues, unless you've set `$ErrorActionPreference` to `'Stop'`.

**Example**:

```
cmd /c 'echo hi >&2'
```

The above prints 'hi' normally in the regular console, but presents like an error in the ISE.

---

Generally, **consider switching from the ISE to  [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell)**:

- all future development effort will focus there
- it doesn't exhibit the problematic behavior at hand

However, note that, **as in the ISE, all code runs dot-sourced in the same session by default, which, as stated, has potentially unwanted side effects when running code repeatedly**.

**To avoid that**, use **setting `"powershell.debugging.createTemporaryIntegratedConsole": true`** to create a *temporary* session for debugging (add it to `settings.json` via `>Preferences: Open Settings`, or check setting `PowerShell > Debugging: Create Temporary Console` in the settings dialog) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71970578/45375) for the behavioral implications.

Comment: Ah. I did notice it interpreted every negative output as an error, that makes sense because it is writing to stderr. I will experiment some more, and get VS code. But there is still the issue of running a script from cmd or PowerShell has a different effect than double clicking it. I think this is the root issue here.

Thank you for your generous time donation to help!

Comment: @Mike: Glad it was at least partially helpful. Can I suggest you remove the part about double-clicking from your question and move it to a _new_ question? That way we have two _focused_ questions with - hopefully - focused answers.

Comment: @Mike: The error message you're seeing when double-clicking appears to be related to `plink.exe` /PuTTY / SSH, though I have no explanation - see https://stackoverflow.com/q/19542246/45375