# Error when creating a New-Object PSObject

Tags: powershell, csv

This powershell script takes up to 8 rows in a csv file and combines them into one row by duplicating the columns, and then saving in a result file (the first result file saved fine).  If there are 16 rows in the csv it is meant to save a second result file etc.

e.g. in rows.csv:

first_field second_field third_field fourth_field

ball bat racket club

orange banana mango pear

In result1.csv:

first1 second1 third1 fourth1 first2 second2 third2 fourth2

ball bat racket club orange banana mango pear

I get an error:

```
New-Object : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.Collections.IDictionary' required by parameter 'Property'. Specified method is not supported.
At C:csv.ps1:19 char:42
+ $results = New-Object PSObject -Property $details
+                                          ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Note that the first new-object creation worked ok on line 16.  In Powershell ISE if I rerun the script it errors on line 16 too.  I have no idea what is wrong here but assume I need to destroy the PSObject after saving each csv file?

```
$csvObjects = import-csv C:\rows.csv
$results = @()
$counter=1
foreach ($item in $csvObjects){
    $detailsnew = [ordered] @{            
        "first$counter" = $item.'First_field'          
        "second$counter" = $item.'Second_field'           
        "third$counter"  = $item.'Third_field'
        "fourth$counter" = $item.'Fourth_field'
    }   
    $details  +=  $detailsnew 
    # modulus comparison returns remainder - write out file every 8
    if ($counter % 8 -eq 0) {
        if ($counter -eq 8) {
            #works on line below on first run but fails on subsequent runs within Powershell ISE
            $results = New-Object PSObject -Property $details 
        }

        if ($counter -eq 16) {
            # fails on line below
            $results2 = New-Object PSObject -Property $details
        }

        $quotient = $counter / 8
        $results | export-csv -Path c:\result"$quotient".csv -noType
        $details = @()
        $results = @()
    }                     
    $counter++           
}
#write out final file if number not divisible by 8
if (-not($counter % 8 -eq 0)) {
    $results += New-Object PSObjectF -Property $details
    $modulo = $counter % 8
    $quotient_plus1 = (($counter-$modulo) / 8) +1
    $results | export-csv -Path C:\result"$quotient_plus1".csv -noType 
}
```

Comment: The issue is you are taking a [Ordered] list and trying to convert it to a PSObject.

Comment: @ArcSet I tried removing [ordered] from the script but got the same error.  I originally added [ordered] to improve readability of the csv file by keeping similar fields together, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- `$details = @()` should be `$details = [ordered] @{}`
- To also make repeated executions *from the ISE* work as intended, place *another* `$details = [ordered] @{}` statement *before* the loop.

---

- In the very first loop iteration, `$details` is initially *undefined*, and  `$details  +=  $detailsnew` assigns the `$detailsnew` (ordered) hash table (an `[ordered] @{ ... }` hash table in PowerShell is of type [`System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary)) *as-is* to `$details` (that is, with `$details` undefined, `+=` effectively behaves the same as `=`).
- The `$detailsnew` hash tables created in the next 7 iterations are then *merged* by `+=` into the hash table already stored in `$details`.
- After the 8th iteration, you mistakenly (re-)initialize `$details` as an *array* (`@()`), which is the source of the problem: subsequent use of `+=` then adds a *new array element* to `$details` instead of merging the hash table entries, and passing an *array* rather than a hash table (or any dictionary type that implements [`System.Collections.IDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IDictionary)) to `New-Object`'s `-Property` parameter then - predictably - fails.

  - Instead, (re)-initialize `$details` as an ordered hash table: `$details = [ordered] @{}`

---

> In Powershell ISE if I rerun the script it errors on line 16 too.

The **PowerShell ISE *dot-sources* the scripts it runs**, which means that **variables from previous invocations can linger**.

As an aside: This **equally applies to [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)** with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell), which you should consider migrating to<sup>[1]</sup>.
However, there **you can opt to create a new, temporary session instead**, as described in the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49417234/45375).

In your case, this means that `$details` already is an *array* in the very first iteration when you re-execute the script in the ISE.

---

<sup>[1] The PowerShell ISE is [no longer actively developed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and [there are reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section).</sup>

Comment: My pleasure, @dapa; good point about the connection between (ordered) hash tables and `IDictionary` not being obvious; I've update the answer to better reflect that