# Powershell Script working fine in Visual Code but fails running from Terminal

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, automation, powershell-3.0, f5

I'm working on writing a script which will run from AzDo Pipeline to disable F5 WebServers. Below script works fine in Visual Code and does disable the server as expected . But when running from the terminal or PS window fails with the below error . Can someone please help.

```
$ServerInput = 'server1.abc.com'
$BIGIPBaseURL = "https://ser-f5-1.prod.abc.com"
$usr = "nilesh"
$SecurePassword='P@assword'
Write-Host "Starting the Script..." 
# Initialize variables
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$BIGIPToken = $null
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green " done!"
$DisableWebServers = $true
# Initialize functions
Write-Host "Initializing functions..." -NoNewline
$PSVersionTable

function Disable-BIGIPNode([string]$NodeName) {
    # servers should use the Disable-BIGIPTelcoNode() function
    Write-Host "In the Disable function"
    if ($NodeName -match "(?i).*telco.*") {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "WARNING: `"$($NodeName.ToUpper().Split('.')[0])`" is in the wrong list.  telcoo hosts should be added to the TelcoServers list in your input file."
        BREAK
    }
    else {
        if ($BIGIPToken -eq $null) {
            Write-Host "Now will enter the Open-Session"
            Open-BIGIPSession
        }

        Write-Host "Disabling node `"$($NodeName.ToUpper().Split('.')[0])`" in BIG-IP..." -NoNewline
        $WebRequestInput = @{
            body = @{
                "session" = "user-disabled"
            } | ConvertTo-Json
            uri = $($BIGIPBaseURL) + "/mgmt/tm/ltm/node/~Common~" + $NodeName.ToLower()
            headers = @{
                "Content-Type" = "application/json"
                "X-F5-Auth-Token" = "$BIGIPToken"
            } 
            method = "PATCH"
        } 
        Write-Host $WebRequestInput
        Write-Host $WebRequestInput.body

        try {
            Write-Host "In the final try block"
            $Request = Invoke-WebRequest @WebRequestInput -UseBasicParsing -SkipCertificateCheck 
        }
        catch {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red " failed!"
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red ($_.ErrorDetails | ConvertFrom-Json).Message
        }
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green " done!"
        $global:ZabbixRequestID++
    }
}

function Open-BIGIPSession() {
    Write-Host "Authenticating with BIG-IP API..." -NoNewline
    $WebRequestInput = @{
        body = @{
            username = "$usr"
            password = "$SecurePassword"
            loginProviderName = "tmos"
        } | ConvertTo-Json
        uri = $ScriptInput.BIGIPBaseURL + "/mgmt/shared/authn/login"
        headers = @{
            "Content-Type" = "application/json"
        }
        method = "POST"
    }
    try {
        [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
        $Request = Invoke-WebRequest @WebRequestInput -UseBasicParsing -SkipCertificateCheck
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red " failed!"
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red ($_.ErrorDetails | ConvertFrom-Json).Message
        EXIT 1
    }
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green " done!"
    $global:BIGIPToken = ($Request.Content | ConvertFrom-Json).token.token 
}

if ($DisableWebServers) {
    Write-Host "Starting the main Methord "
    foreach ($Server in $($ServerInput)) {
        Disable-BIGIPNode -NodeName $Server
    }
}
```

The PowerShell version is PSVersion                      7.2.2

```
Disabling node "SAC-DEV-WEB2" in BIG-IP...System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry
{
  "session": "user-disabled"
}
In the final try block
 failed!
ConvertFrom-Json: C:\Temp\Testing.ps1:49:64
Line |
  49 |  … Host -ForegroundColor Red ($_.ErrorDetails | ConvertFrom-Json).Messag …
     |                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Conversion from JSON failed with error: Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: U. Path '', line
     | 3, position 4.
```

Its working fine when running from VsCode but fails if called with the file name from the same terminal

like .\Testing.ps1

Please help

Comment: As an aside: the `break` statement inside your `Disable-BIGIPNode` function breaks out of your `foreach ($Server in $($ServerInput))` loop, i.e. if there are servers remaining, they won't be processed - is that the intent?

Comment: @mklement0 if ($NodeName -match "(?i).*telco.*") is just to get out of the loop if the server name contains telco name in it , the issue thats happening here is it fails while creating the token

Comment: I see (my suggestion would be to move the break logic into the `foreach` loop, as that is conceptually clearer). As for the error: The true error is being obscured by the follow-up error stemming from `.ErrorDetails` not containing valid JSON, so I'd start with printing the true error with `Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red $_`

Answer (score 5):

- Your *incidental* problem is that the true error message is being obscured by a follow-up error that results from attempting to parse the error record's `.ErrorDetails` property as JSON, which it isn't. (You report that examining the true error reveals a *401 authentication error*).
- I have no specific explanation for the difference in behavior you're seeing between running in Visual Studio Code vs. in a regular PowerShell console, but I have a *guess*:

  - Your Visual Studio Code session in the so-called PowerShell Integrated Console may have *lingering state* from *earlier* debugging runs, which may *mask a bug* in your script.
  - Restarting Visual Studio Code should clarify whether that is the case, but there's also a way to configure the PowerShell extension so that the problem doesn't arise to begin with - see below.

---

- **By default, code you run (debug) via the [Visual Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell) executes in the *same* PowerShell session, *directly in the global scope***.

  - That is, running a script being edited, say, `foo.ps1`, in the debugger is effectively the same as invoking it with `. .\foo.ps1`, i.e. it is in effect [*dot-sourced*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-).
  - **Therefore, a given debugging run can be affected by *earlier* runs**, because the state of earlier runs *lingers*.

    - This **can result in bugs going undetected**, such as in the following example:

      - Say your script defines variable `$foo` and uses it throughout the script. If you debug your script at least one, `$foo` is now defined in the PowerShell session in the PowerShell Integrated Console.
      - Say you then change the name to `$bar`, but you forget to also replace (all) *references* to `$foo` with `$bar`.
      - Your script is now effectively broken, but you won't notice in the same session, because `$foo` is still around from earlier debugging runs.

        - However, running the script from a regular PowerShell console *would* surface the problem.
  - The [obsolescent *Windows PowerShell ISE*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) exhibits the same unfortunate  behavior, *invariably* so, but fortunately there *is* a solution for the PowerShell extension - see next point.
- You can **avoid this problem by activating the `Create Temporary Integrated Console` setting** (via `File > Preferences > Settings` or <kbd>Ctrl+,</kbd>), which ensures that **every debugging run creates a *new, temporary session* to run in**, which starts with a clean slate:

  - Whenever a new temporary session is started, any previous one is automatically discarded.
  - A temporary session has prefix `[TEMP]`  in the list of running shells in the integrated terminal.
  - You pay a performance penalty, because a new PowerShell session must be created for every run, and you lose the previous session's display output - but I suspect avoiding the pitfalls of lingering state is worth the price.
  - Note that, in a given temporary session, the dot-sourced invocation described above still applies, but with the lingering-state problem out of the picture, it can now be considered an advantage: After the script finishes, and before the temporary session is replaced with a new one, the variables and functions defined in the script's top-level scope are then available for inspection.