# My use of Out-File and/or [system.io.file]::WriteAllText

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.3

Both commands work when running inside Visual Studio Code but if I execute the ps1 file directly in pwsh 7 the file is blank. Same if I right-click and select Open With pwsh.

Tried both commands, out-file first but moved to [system.io.file]::WriteAllText to remove blank rows. Both successfully create and populate a csv file as expected when I execute it from within Visual Studio Code.

```
try {
    $files = @()
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\networkShare\ps1files"
    #$files = $files + (get-childitem -Path "\\networkShare\ps1files2")
    $results = foreach ($file in $files) {
        if ($file.FullName.substring($file.FullName.length - 3, 3) -eq "ps1") {
            #Write-Host $file
            $scriptblock = [scriptblock]::Create((Get-Content -Raw -Path $file.FullName))
            $ast = $scriptblock.Ast
            $commands = $ast.FindAll( { $args[0] -is [System.Management.Automation.Language.CommandAst] }, $true)
            $commandText = foreach ($command in $commands) {
                $command.CommandElements[0].Extent.Text
            }
            $commandText | 
            Select-Object -Unique | 
            Sort-Object | 
            Select-Object @{
                Label      = "Module"
                Expression = { (Get-Command $_).Source.Substring(0, (Get-Command $_).Source.Length) }
            }

    
            $value = ""
            foreach ($result in $results) {
                if ($result.Module -inotlike "C:*") {
                    if ($value -inotlike "*" + $result.Module + "*") {
                        $value = $value + $result.Module + "`n"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $ModulesInUse = @()
    $NewModules = @()
    $NewestMod = @()
    #$NewestMod = ""
    $ModulesInUse = Import-Csv \\networkShare\PSModulesUsed.csv -Header "Module"
    $NewModules = $results.Where({ $_.module -notin $ModulesInUse.Module -and $_.Module.Length -gt 0 -and $_.Module -inotlike "C:*" })
    if ($NewModules.count -gt 0) { 
        Write-Host "New Modules found `n"
        # Create unique array of new modules found
        foreach ( $mod in $NewModules ) {
            if ($mod.Module -notin $NewestMod.Module) {
                $NewestMod = $NewestMod + $mod
            }
        }
        $NewestMod.module
        Write-Host `n
        $Prompt = 'Do you want to update the Modules Used csv file now? Y/N'
        $UpdateFile = Read-Host -Prompt $Prompt
    
        if ($UpdateFile -eq 'y') {
            #$value | Out-File "\\networkShare\PSModulesUsed.csv"
            [system.io.file]::WriteAllText(“\\networkShare\PSModulesUsed.csv”, $value)
        }
    }

    else {
        Read-Host "No new Modules found. Press any key to exit"
    }
```

Comment: Out-File and [system.io.file]::WriteAllText() work...so if you're having a problem you should probably share your code.

Comment: It's propably an issue with relative paths and current directory. Try to use absolute paths everywhere. E. g. to load a file relative to your script, specify `$PSScriptRoot\SomeFile.txt`. This makes you independent from the current directory.

Comment: I am using a complete path for both methods:
$value | Out-File "\\fileshare\folder\PSModulesUsed.csv"
[system.io.file]::WriteAllText(“\\fileshare\folder\PSModulesUsed.csv”, $value)

Comment: By default, _state lingers_ between (debugging) runs in Visual Studio Code, unfortunately. To rule that out ad hoc, restart Visual Studio Code. To rule that out methodically, configure the PowerShell extension to create a new, temporary session for every (debugging) run - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71970578/45375)

Comment: Okay, so I followed what you said mklement0 and stopped the "state linger", now writing to the file does NOT work from Code either. I am not getting any failures. I added a read-host after the save step to delay closing the session but it did NOT help. Neither did a different type of pause like timeout /t 7 /nobreak

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks to mklement0!!!
Making that change to Code revealed the $value I was sending was not correct, even though it was working before. When running outside of Code it was blank.
I moved the code below to outside the $Results block of code and it works now.

```
    $value = ""
    foreach ($result in $results) {
        if ($result.Module -inotlike "C:*") {
            if ($value -inotlike "*" + $result.Module + "*") {
                $value = $value + $result.Module + "`n"
            }
        }
    }
```