# Split returns and chat GCP understanding

Tags: powershell

Code

```
$FilePath = 'c:\temp\test.csv'
            
# Use the file path in your script
$Entry = Get-Content -Path $FilePath -raw
$Entry = $Entry -split "\r?\n"
    
# Initialize the $Result array
$Result = @()

# Loop through each email address in the array
foreach ($Email in $Entry) {
    $ValidEmail = $null
    $Value = $null
    # Remove leading and trailing spaces, and replace middle spaces with dots
    $Value = $Email.Trim() -replace '\s+', '.'

    try {
        # Try to create a new mail address object to validate the address
        $ValidEmail = (New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress $Value).Address
    }
    catch {
        # If there is an exception, ignore it and move on to the next validation method
        # Try to extract the email address from a display name format
        if ($Value -match '(?<!<)(?<Email>\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}\b)(?!>)') {
            $ValidEmail = $matches['Email']
        }
        else {
            # If all else fails, try to form a valid address by stripping and adding
            $ValidEmail = ($Value -replace '[<>,()@,]', '' -replace '\s+', '.' -replace '[^A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+', '') + '@Domain.com'
        }
    }

    # Add the valid email address to the $Result array
    $Result += $ValidEmail
}
    
# Return the valid email addresses
return $Result
```

When I run above in VSCode and pause on the line `$Entry = $Entry -split "\r?\n"`
The answer is correct

If I close vscode, open it and run the script with no debug the answer is wrong.

Test data

```
Mark Gonzalez
Dan.Ca@domain.com
Jennifer Zal <jennifer.zal@domain.com>
```

Debug answer

```
Mark.Gonzalez@domain.com
Dan.Ca@domain.com
Jennifer.Zald@domain.com
```

Script just run

```
Mark.Gonzalez.Dan.Ca@domain.com.Jennifer.Zal
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- There's no obvious explanation for your symptom; on a general note, a notable pitfall when using the **PIC (PowerShell Integrated Console)** in Visual Studio Code is that ***state can linger between runs*, potentially affecting subsequent runs** - ***unless* you configure the PIC to start a *new, temporary session* for each debugging run** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71970578/45375).
- I suggest streamlining your code as follows, which not only improves its efficiency, but may make the problem go away:

```bash
$FilePath = 'c:\temp\test.csv'

# This outputs the modified lines directly.
Get-Content $FilePath |
  ForEach-Object {
    $addr = $_ -replace '^.*<|>.*$'
    try {
      ([System.Net.Mail.MailAddress] $addr).Address
    } catch {
      $addr.Trim() -replace '[^a-z0-9._%+-]' -replace '\s+', '.'
    }
  }
```

Comment: i have been thinking that maybe i need to produce a new variable here `$Entry = $Entry -split "\r?\n"` but I don't know why?
I will look at what you wrote.

Comment: Error: `Method invocation failed because [System.Net.Mail.MailAddress] does not contain a method named 'TryCreate'`

Comment: @dcaz, I didn't realize that `::TryCreate()` works in [_PowerShell (Core) 7+_](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) only. Please see my update, which shows a solution that works in both PowerShell editions.