# Why does this code keep adding to the array, even after it is cleared?

Tags: arrays, powershell, variables, scope

The code below will keep adding to an array, even after it's been cleared.

```
...
#Refresh Printer List

[Array]$Servers = "VSRPRN007","VSRPRN008"

    foreach ($Server in $Servers){
        [Array]$arrPrinters = get-printer -ComputerName $Server | Select-Object name, ComputerName | Sort-Object name
        foreach ($Printer in $arrPrinters){
            $cbbPrinters.items.add($Printer.name) | Out-Null
            [Array]$Printers += $Printer
        }
    }

$button.Add_Click({
    $SelectedPrinter = $cbbPrinters.SelectedItem

    $Printer = $Printers | Where-object {$_.Name -eq $SelectedPrinter}
    $Printers = $null
    Write-host $Printer.Name, $printer.ComputerName
    Write-host $Printers.Count
...
```

if i manually type

```
$Printers = $Null
```

it successfully clears the array. but when the script tries to `$null` the variable, it somehow keeps its value. this code will return

2nd run:
#Printer# #Printer# #SERVER# #SERVER#

3rd run:
#Printer# #Printer# #Printer# #SERVER# #SERVER# #SERVER#

4th Run:
#Printer# #Printer# #Printer# #Printer# #SERVER# #SERVER# #SERVER# #SERVER#

as opposed to the following on every run of the code:

#Printer# #SERVER#

Comment: In short: Event handlers run in a _child scope_, so in order to create or update a variable in the script's scope, you must use `$script:variable = ...`, otherwise you'll implicitly create a _block-local_ variable. See the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: Your symptom suggests that you're either running from the Windows PowerShell ISE or Visual Studio Code. The former _invariably_ and the latter _by default_ runs code _dot-sourced_, i.e. directly in the global scope, so that _state lingers_ and previous runs can affect subsequent ones. The ISE is best avoided these days - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375). To avoid the problem in Visual Studio Code, configure the PowerShell extension to create a new, temporary session for every run - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71970578/45375).

Comment: With dot-sourcing in the picture, the problem with the `$Printers` array growing between runs could be avoided by unconditionally initializing the variable first (`$Printers = @()`), before the `foreach ($Server in $Servers)` loop.